# Changing button content on click event function does not work c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Sooo my problem is as follow, I am running a function on button click event, I want to simply change the button content to show the end user that stuff is busy loading but running some code in the function aswell makes it becoming "unresponsive" in a way, I did some research and tried `async void` and `await` and did not work, this is an example of my code:

```
private void Clicked_Example(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Content = "Loading...";   //I need this to be shown before proceeding...

    //Sooo here I am running some MySQL queries and Mqtt messages and... uhhm well the random usual stuff...

    button1.Content = "Done!";    //I need this then to be changed after
}
```

Sad to say but I'm not much experienced in updating the UI from threads.
Please any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your queries on the UI thread, which prevents the UI thread from drawing your updates. You will need to put the queries on a background thread. There are a number of ways to do this. Using `async`/`await` with `Task` is one simple way:

```
private async void Clicked_Example(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Content = "Loading...";
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // run your queries here, but do not update your UI within this block
        }
    );
    button1.Content = "Done!";
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh nice! i got the async/await all wrong before, i made some unnecessary mistakes, I got it working now thanks!

Comment: @kilroyabstergo: Be forewarned that nothing you do in the code that is running as a result of your `Task.Run` call can do anything in the UI (for example, don't run one query, update something in the UI and then continue with another query). Only the UI thread can play with the UI

Comment: Thanks for the hint!